# Copy files from remote Unix machine to windows

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, scp, file-transfer

I have a remote Unix machine which doesnt have SMB installed and I cannot install it. However there are some files located on that server that I need on a windows machine.

What I need is a way to periodically copy a number of specific files from the Unix machine based on a list of filenames I have on my windows machine.

How would I go about doing this? - This has to happen automatically once a day.

I'm thinking a little scheduled job on windows that reads a needed files' names in and then opens a ssh tunnel and runs a scp command remotely and copying each file. Is this a good solution or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Cygwin on the windows machine and use the "scp" command.
Files can be "pulled" from the *nix machine over to the windows machine like this:

```
$> scp user@nixbox:/var/log/importantlogs/*.zip .
```

Comment: This looks interesting.. would it be possible to have a list of filenames and then run some java job which would run the above command for each fil in the list?

Comment: Java is maybe a little overkill to copy files. A simple bash script should do the job.

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering just making a little bashscript to run on the unix machine and add it as a cron job. Maybe I'll learn a little unix then..

Comment: @Herter: an even simpler solution

Comment: @Herter: an even simpler solution in bash: `for i in file1.txt file2.bin file3.ext; do scp user@nixbox:/var/log/logdir/$i . ; done` should copy over all the files matching the filenames you specified.

Answer (score 1):

[File Transfer Protocol (aka FTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp)

Setup an FTP server on either machine (suggestion: let UNIX be the server), and connect as client from the other machine.

You can automatize any behavior over FTP using scripts.

Comment: Cannot install anything on the unix machine I only have read permission on it..

Comment: Do it reverse then: server on Windows, client on UNIX. You should have write permissions on the directory of course.

Comment: I'll try out the scp command first.. if I cannot get that working I'll look into your suggestion. I'll give you a +1 for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Deltacopy and rsync?

http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

In general terms, DeltaCopy is an open source, fast incremental backup program. Let's say you have to backup one file that is 500 MB every night. A normal file copy would copy the entire file even if a few bytes have changed. DeltaCopy, on the other hand, would only copy the part of file that has actually been modified. This reduces the data transfer to just a small fraction of 500 MB saving time and network bandwidth.

Here is a list of features

- Incremental backup - Copies part of the file that is actually modified
- Task scheduler - Profiles in DeltaCopy can run based on a schedule
- Email notification - Administrators can receive email confirmation on successful as well as failed transfers
- One-click restore - Backed up files can be easily restored.
- Windows friendly environment - No need to manually modify configuration files or play around with command line options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I cannot install anything on the unix machine.